# cron Symfony2 to delete a file

Tags: symfony, cron

I would like to create a cron that remove a file every 24hrs but it doesn't work for me !

emptyCache.php  permission 755

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

I use for that a cron from OVH to do the job, I follow the process but the folder wasn't removed! My question is: is it the right command?

Comment: So what's your question? Permission problem? Is this a error message you've posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of script which should work on a OVH hosting ([Pro 2014](https://www.ovh.com/hebergement-web/hebergement-pro.xml)), you don't need to use any PHP or Symfony2 file or command:

File: <kbd>/homez.807/[my_login]/symfony2/launch_commands.php</kbd>

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /homez.807/[my_login]/symfony2/app/cache/*
```

It's simpler to put the full path of the directory you want to erase, but you can also use the `cd` command to change the directory then delete the sub-directory.

And here is the configuration in the OVH manager (see the *Cron* tab):

[image: Crone]

So the `./` is the root of you web hosting, corresponding to `/homez.807/[my_login]/`. Here are the two important options :

- Script: we have to put the relative path (from the root of the web hosting) of the script: `symfony2/launch_commands.sh`
- Language: *Other* because the script should be executed by the shell, not the PHP interpreter
- Logs: you should enable logs in order to send the result of the cron task by email
- Description: choose an explicit name